# htaccess file not working on server and redirecting not properly while working on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am setting up something on my server,

http://adamcyber.net/talentmasterdemo/

If i copy the db and the application and run it to localhost, everything works fine with changing the configurations to the localhost settings like paths and subdirectories. But when i upload it the the server adamcyber.net. The login page works fine, but when i login with the credentials. it goes to infinite loop of redirection. so firefox shows error. What i figured out till now is that it's the htaccess problem, but i am not sure that y htaccess is working on localhost and not working on the server, The is configured to run htaccess properly, so no issues in running htaccess as other sites on the server are properly running htaccess. Below is the htaccess file code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

I am stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i tried the code provided by you, it's taking to the main site, 404 page, The Main site is a blog of wordpress and the page it's redirecting to says that Page Not Found

Comment: Oh I see. The code i posted will work for your wordpress site and should be located in your root httpdocs folder. For what you have installed at http://adamcyber.net/talentmasterdemo/, you'll need a separate htaccess file in that folder. I assume thats where the code you posted is located? Also. i did a quick user/password combo to see if there were any server errors and i noticed it sent back some database errors. maybe your problem is elsewhere?

Comment: Also, make sure your htaccess file has the correct permissions. if you manually uploaded it and didn't change permissions... it might not even be usable and that would explain why it worked locally but not on the server

Comment: OK, I found one problem , that My page after verifying the login credentials redirects to adamcyber.net/talentmasterdemo/CompanyDashboard , which is not working. But if i put it like, adamcyber.net/talentmasterdemo/index.php/CompanyDashboard. It works . Can you please give a solution in htaccess for that index.php issue

Comment: htaccess is performing good, now just the problem is that index.php in the url. If i put index.php in the URL like adamcyber.net/talentmasterdemo/index.php/CompanyDashboard , it works perfect. But the application redirects default to /CompanyDashboard without index.php . Can we do something about it in htaccess to rewrite the url

Comment: sounds like that's something native to the app your working with. you may want to add a tag for that software as this sounds like it's out of regular htaccess/apache issues and something you need to configure in your software.